# SFINAE std::enable_if fails in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I was trying to port an open sourced project from linux to window, there are some code that compiles perfectly in linux using either g++ or clang++, but I cannot compile it under MSVC 2015, could anyone tell me how to fix it or how to get around it? I appreciate very much for your help!!!

> Here is the code (I have simplified it so you can focus on the key stuff)

```
template <typename T, class IsMatch = void>
class vc_hashkey
{
public:
    static constexpr bool holds_value() { return false; }
};

template <typename T>
class vc_hashkey<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{
public:
    static constexpr bool holds_value() { return true; }
};

template <typename T, class IsMatch = void>
class vc_hashkey_and_value
{
};

template <typename T>
class vc_hashkey_and_value<T, typename std::enable_if<vc_hashkey<T>::holds_value()>::type>
{
};
```

That's it, I did not even used these code pieces in my main function. When I tried to compile, the msvc 2015 update RC1 compiler gives me compile errors on the partial specialization of the **class vc_hashkey_and_value**, saying:

> C2039 'type': is not a member of 'std::enable_if<'false, void>'
>
> C2146 syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'type'
>
> C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Is this a MSVC compiler error, thanks for helping me!!!

Comment: ***Yet*** another reason not to use that (with respect to conformance) crappy compiler. It never fully supported C99, neither C11, neither C++11, and definitively won't C++1z... It is literally stuck in the past millenium...

Comment: Looks like it has some problems with using `constexpr` functions in the template argument list of partial specializations. Don't really surprise me, since `constexpr` support is new to VS2015.

Comment: Any idea on how to get a workaround on this?

Comment: Oh maybe I can replace constexpr function with constexpr variable? Let me try~