# trait which detects if a type is no-throw swappable, for msvc also

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-studio-2015, sfinae

I needed a simple type trait to detect if things are no-throw swappable. There is none in the standard library, so I wrote this one. It works in gcc and clang, at least I used it without problems for a few months.

Today I am trying to compile also with MSVC 2015, and it gives a very terse compilation error which I would like to understand.

Here is an MVCE:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// Code is targetting C++11 so we have to backport this:
template <bool b, typename V = void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<b, V>::type;

namespace detail {
  using std::swap;

  // Need to use SFINAE for this in case there is no `swap`.
  template <typename T, typename ENABLE = void>
  struct is_nothrow_swappable : std::false_type {};

  template <typename T>
  struct is_nothrow_swappable<T, enable_if_t<noexcept(
                                   swap(*static_cast<T *>(nullptr),
                                        *static_cast<T *>(nullptr)))>>
    : std::true_type {};
} // end namespace detail

// Tests

static_assert(detail::is_nothrow_swappable<int>::value, "");
static_assert(detail::is_nothrow_swappable<std::pair<int, int>>::value, "");

struct B {};

static_assert(detail::is_nothrow_swappable<B>::value, "");

struct A {
  A() = delete;
  A(A&&) = delete;
};

static_assert(!detail::is_nothrow_swappable<A>::value, "");

int main() {}
```

On [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) I reproduce the error mentioned:

```
Error(s):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\utility(49): error C2057: expected constant expression
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\utility(48): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::swap<T>(_Ty &,_Ty &) noexcept(<expr>)' being compiled
source_file.cpp(6): error C2039: 'type': is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,V>'
        with
        [
            V=void
        ]
source_file.cpp(18): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'type'
source_file.cpp(18): error C2938: 'enable_if_t<false,void>' : Failed to specialize alias template
source_file.cpp(18): error C2059: syntax error: '<end Parse>'
source_file.cpp(24): error C2338: 
source_file.cpp(25): error C2338: 
source_file.cpp(29): error C2338:
```

Okay, MSVC says it's not a constant expression, but exactly what and why?

Is this basically a bug in msvc `constexpr` support?

Or, is this what "expression SFINAE" means, and the error is because msvc doesn't support it? If so can I workaround it?

Is this not actually valid C++11 code, which simply happens to be accepted by gcc and clang?

---

After browsing around, I found a WG proposal for `std::is_nothrow_swappable`, with an appendix and example code, which differs from mine somewhat:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0185r1.html#Appendix

This implementation compiles on all machines:

```
struct do_is_nothrow_swappable
{
  template<class T>
  static auto test(int) -> std::integral_constant<bool,
    noexcept(swap(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<T&>()))
  >;

  template<class>
  static std::false_type test(...);
};

template <typename T>
struct is_nothrow_swappable : decltype(
  do_is_nothrow_swappable::test<T>(0)
)
{};
```

So my problem is effectively solved, but the question is, why actually does the one work and the other fail? What was actually wrong with my attempt? If you can explain I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Duplicate with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591226/sfinae-stdenable-if-fails-in-visual-studio-2015?

Comment: I think that question is not related to this one. A few lines at the end of the error log are similar, but the important part is the first error, where it (seems to) say this `noexcept` expression is not a constant expression. Idk, what makes you think it's a dupe?

Comment: The `noexcept` operator performs a compile-time check that returns true if an expression is declared to not throw any exceptions. It's definitely a constant expression

Comment: Yeah, I know what `noexcept` is supposed to mean but what I don't know is what is going with msvc here. I guess it's not actually *my* `noexcept` that isn't giving a constant expression, the error message seems to say, it is whatever is in MSVC's <utility> header that it is putting in the `noexcept` qualifier for `std::swap` function? `note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::swap<T>(_Ty &,_Ty &) noexcept(<expr>)' being compiled` I'm not sure entirely what this line means

Comment: This is probably a MSVC bug as the compiler instantiates the template without an actual type and then chokes on the noexcept specification of swap (which is detected as not being a constant expression). This code is sufficient to make MSVC fail: `using std::swap; template <class T> struct is_nothrow_swappable : std::integral_constant<bool,noexcept(swap(*(T*)nullptr, *(T*)nullptr))> {};`